# Registration Security and Validation / Server vs Client: ASP/Javascript/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, validation

I am creating a Registration page using ASP, Javascript, and HTML/CSS and I have a few questions... the code is working, but I want to perform validation in a secure way. From my understanding, hackers can inject script into the URL.

1. Is ASP the `@ { content here }` section?
2. Is ASP performed by the server (not the client)?
3. Is ASP secure to perform validation? I am checking if the emails match, passwords match, and password meets the length requirements.
4. I currently perform validation in the Javascript `<script>` section. Should it be done in the `@ { content here }`?
5. I created a `checkUser` in the `@ { content here }` section. I want to check if the user's `email1` exists in the database already. I was trying to perform this check in the `@ { if(isPost) }` section. I cannot get this to work. This is not a question, but I need some help here with the approach.

ASP??

```
   @{
    Page.Title = "Register";
    var minPass = 5;
    var maxPass = 10;
    var email1 = "";
    var pass1 = "";
    var db = Database.Open("Resume");
    var userCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = '1@1'";
    var userInsert = "INSERT INTO USR (EMAIL, PSWD) VALUES (@0, @1)";


if(IsPost) {
    email1 = Request.Form["email1"];
    pass1 = Request.Form["pass1"];
    //if (userCheck != "0") { return x; }
    db.Execute(userInsert, email1, pass1);
    Response.Redirect("~/Default");
    }
}
```

HTML/CSS

```
<style>header {visibility: hidden;}</style>
<body class="bg100">
    <div class="sq100">
        <form id="fm101" method="post">
            <table class="tab100" style="border: 15px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold;">MyLink</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sitename">Register</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="td100" style="color: #f00"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></br>Email Address:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="em100" type="email" name="email1" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></br>Confirm Email Address:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="em101" type="email" name="email2" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></br>Password @minPass-@maxPass Characters:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="pw100" type="password" name="pass1" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></br>Confirm Password:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="pw101" type="password" name="pass2" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 10px;"></br><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="regValidation();"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 10px;"></br><input type="button" Value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:location.href='Default.cshtml'"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function regValidation()
    {
        document.getElementById('td100').innerHTML = "";
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; 

        var error = "";
        var email1 = document.getElementById('em100').value;
        var email2 = document.getElementById('em101').value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById('pw100').value;
        var pass2 = document.getElementById('pw101').value;

        if (!document.getElementById('em100').checkValidity()) error += "</br>Emails are not valid.";
        if (email1 !== email2) error += "</br>Emails do not match.";
        if (pass1 !== pass2) error += "</br>Passwords do not match.";
        if (pass1.length < @minPass || pass1.length > @maxPass) error += "</br>Password must be @minPass - @maxPass characters.";

        if (error !== "")
        {
            document.getElementById('td100').innerHTML = error
        } else {
        return true && regSuccess();
        }
    }

    function regSuccess()
    {
        alert("Thank you for signing up!");
        document.getElementById('fm101').submit();
        return;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is ASP the @ { content here } section? This is ASP.NET Razor (webpages)

Is ASP performed by the server (not the client)? Server

Is ASP secure to perform validation? I am checking if the emails match, passwords match, and password meets the length requirements. Yes

I currently perform validation in the Javascript  section. Should it be done in the @ { content here }? Javascript can be injected by a hacker, perform validation in asp.

I created a checkUser in the @ { content here } section. I want to check if the user's email1 exists in the database already. I was trying to perform this check in the @ { if(isPost) } section. I cannot get this to work. This is not a question, but I need some help here with the approach. Please see my solution at: [Razor and JS Trouble: Check If User Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653435/razor-and-js-trouble-check-if-user-exists/45678604#45678604)