# Razor and JS Trouble: Check If User Exists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to verify that a user does not exist. I cannot figure out how to send @email1 or @0. I tried it several ways. **I can get it to work** when I hard code the WHERE CLAUSE. For example, an email I know exists is doug@fresh.com. This works: `"var userCheck = "SELECT * FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = 'doug@fresh.com'".Count()`

These do **not** work: I have tried `var userCheck = "SELECT * FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = " +email1.Count();` and `"var userCheck = "SELECT * FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = @0".Count()`

Do I have to pass `email1` as a parameter???

ASP.NET- Razor:

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Register";
    var minPass = 2;
    var maxPass = 100;
    var email1 = "";
    var pass1 = "";
    var db = Database.Open("Resume");
    var userCheck = "SELECT * FROM USR WHERE EMAIL = " +email1;
    var userInsert = "INSERT INTO USR (EMAIL, PSWD) VALUES (@0, @1)";


    if(IsPost) {
        email1 = Request.Form["email1"];
        pass1 = Request.Form["pass1"];
        db.Execute(userInsert, email1, pass1);
        Response.Redirect("~/Default");
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
var error = "";
var email1 = document.getElementById('em100').value;
var email2 = document.getElementById('em101').value;
var pass1 = document.getElementById('pw100').value;
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pw101').value;

if (@userCheck > 0) error += "</br>Email already exists."; // ?????????????????
if (!document.getElementById('em100').checkValidity()) error += "</br>Emails are not valid.";
if (email1 !== email2) error += "</br>Emails do not match.";
if (pass1 !== pass2) error += "</br>Passwords do not match.";
if (pass1.length < minPass || pass1.length > maxPass) error += "</br>Password must be minPass - maxPass characters.";
```

Comment: `email1` is an empty string when you build up your query. Should be pretty obvious to you. Anyways, don't form queries by concatenating strings together. That's a recipe for a SQL Injection attack. You should use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to comment that my approach was entirely wrong.

I am no longer using Javascript for validation, but only ASP.NET Razor.

For those who are struggling with a similar thing, below is my solution:

Be sure to include `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ResumeLink", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);`

```
@{ 
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    var confirmPassword = "";
    var regMsg = "";
    var minPass = 2;
    var maxPass = 5;


    if (!IsPost) {
    if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
        regMsg = String.Format("You are already logged in. (User name: {0})", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
        }
    }

    if (IsPost){
    WebSecurity.Logout();    
    username = Request["username"];
    password = Request["password"];
    confirmPassword = Request["confirmPassword"];

    try {
        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(username);
    } catch {
        regMsg += "Invalid email format.";
    }

    //Validation.Add("username", Validator.Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$", regMsg += "Invalid email format."));
    if (password != confirmPassword) {regMsg += "</br>Passwords don't match.";}
    if (WebSecurity.UserExists(username)) {regMsg += String.Format("</br>User '{0}' already exists.", username);}
    if (password.Length < minPass || password.Length > maxPass) {regMsg += "</br>Password doesn't meet length requirement.";}
    if (regMsg == "") {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username,password,null,false);
        regMsg = String.Format("{0} created.", username);
        Response.Write("Registration Successful!");
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.cshtml");
        }
    }
}

<style>header {visibility: hidden;}</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                @if(regMsg != ""){
                    <span class="errorMessage">@Html.Raw(regMsg)</span>
                }
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="username">Email Address:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value='@Request["username"]' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password @minPass-@maxPass Characters:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
            </p>   
            <p>
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label><br/>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:location.href='Default.cshtml'" />
            </p>   
            <p>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```